# My WordPress project on the live server is not enqueuing JS files (404 Error Recieved)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, server, fonts

I am developing a custom Wordpress Theme, however once I load the project to the live server it stops enqueuing my JS files - and provides me with a 404 Error.

Additionally, I am experiencing this same issue with all of my loaded font files and CSS stylesheet

These files load correctly on my local host and only break when I load them onto the live server.

I have looked into wp_enqueue_script() and
wp_enqueue_style(), however I am still experiencing this issue.

My functions.php file includes the following script:

```
function custom_theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-theme-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), '20190512', 'all' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jqueryScripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jqueryScripts.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sierra_ridge_scripts' );
```

The result of the above script is a [404 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQfTJ.png) that appears in the debugger console.

Comment: 404 because it can't find the files in the specified path. Check on view source and see where actually it's looking for and and where your files are. It would help you figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can call wrong function in add_action if you check your code you get idea.

```
function custom_theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-theme-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), '20190512', 'all' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jqueryScripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jqueryScripts.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_theme_scripts' );
```

Please try with this code and check again.